# Email notifications solspace calendar

Tags: craft3, events, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm considering the Solspace Calendar plugin for a project.

1. Can the plugin send automatic e-mail notifications when an event has been submitted from the front-end?
2. Can the plugin save events submitted from the front-end as drafts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Currently this isn't possible out of the box with Calendar. Perhaps there's some other plugin or custom module that can allow for this.
2. You cannot save them as Drafts, but they can be submitted as Disabled if you like. Just be sure to include the following hidden fields in your form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="enabledForSite" value="0" />
```